# KSQLDB connection refused to Kafka Connect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, ksqldb

I am doing PoC on KSQLDB Elasticsearch connector.

I am following from 2 documents online:

One:

```
https://ksqldb.io/quickstart.html
```

All working fine and well and after I fallowed

Second one:

```
https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/build-a-streaming-pipeline/demo_build-a-streaming-pipeline.adoc
```

I am getting this issue when I run this command:

```
CREATE SINK CONNECTOR SINK_ES_sample_1 WITH (
    'connector.class' = 'io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector',
    'topics'          = 'sample_1',
    'connection.url'  = 'http://localhost:9200',
    'type.name'       = '_doc',
    'key.ignore'      = 'false',
    'schema.ignore'   = 'true',
    'transforms'= 'ExtractTimestamp',
    'transforms.ExtractTimestamp.type'= 'org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.InsertField$Value',
    'transforms.ExtractTimestamp.timestamp.field' = 'sample_1'
);
```

Error:

> io.confluent.ksql.util.KsqlServerException:
> org.apache.hc.client5.http.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to
> http://localhost:8083 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused
> (Connection refused) Caused by:
> org.apache.hc.client5.http.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to
> http://localhost:8083 [localhost/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection
> refused   (Connection refused) Caused by: Could not connect to the
> server. Please check the server details are   correct and that the
> server is running.

Answer (score 2):

That suggests that you've misconfigured the ksqlDB server in its connection to Kafka Connect.

If you're following [that demo script](https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/build-a-streaming-pipeline/demo_build-a-streaming-pipeline.adoc) then you should use [the associated Docker Compose file](https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/build-a-streaming-pipeline/docker-compose.yml) which is [configured correctly](https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/build-a-streaming-pipeline/docker-compose.yml#L171):

```
      KSQL_KSQL_CONNECT_URL: http://kafka-connect-01:8083
```